# Foreign Currencies Exchange Data

Tags: currency, data-request, exchange-rates

I need data for forex rates because I'm working on a project to predict the rise and fall of the rates. Where can I find such data?

Comment: I found googling 'Foreign Currencies Exchange Data' was a great start.

Comment: http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates/

Comment: Might be worth flagging to ask a moderator to migrate the question to [opendata.se]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a proper question for this network, but try:

- http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/PA.NUS.FCRF
- https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/param_rms_mth.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following website helpful:

http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/currency-rates/